# Another cannot read props on callback

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-accounts

On the submit button I'm checking if the user is ok.
But I can't access to my props on the callback.

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword({username:username}, password, function(error){
  if(!error){
    this.props.router.push('/');
  }
});


  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
     username: '' ,
     password:'',
     errors: [],
     alertVisible: false
 };
```

My button:

```
<Button type='submit'  onClick={this.onClickLogIn.bind(this)}>Go</Button>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword({username:username}, password, (error) => {
  if(!error){
    this.props.router.push('/ltr/dashboard');
  }
});
```